# How can I modify an existing object to be deferred?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui, jquery-deferred

I'm using a 3rd part library that returns objects that do not allow me to use callbacks like .done(), .always() and so forth. Is it possible to modify these objects to be deferred objects so that I can use these callbacks?

In particular I'm using the kendo scheduler and the object is ...

```
$('div#schedule').kendoScheduler();
```

I would like to modify it so I can do

```
$('div#schedule').kendoScheduler().always(someFunction());
```

Thanks

Comment: If it provides callbacks when it finishes doing things, yes. If not, no.

Comment: Hook up your someFunctions into the kendo function callbacks. Kendo handles all this for you already.